# $\left(R/\langle a\rangle\right)/\langle \overline b\rangle\cong R/\langle a,b\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit and $a,b\in R$.

In order to understand a theorem, I need to prove that $$\left(R/\langle a\rangle\right)/\langle \overline b\rangle\cong R/\langle a,b\rangle$$

I'm trying to find a surjective homomorphism between $R/\langle a\rangle$ and $R/\langle a, b\rangle$ with kernel $\langle \overline  b\rangle$ without success.

I need help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

There is really only one homomorphism to choose, $r+(a) \rightarrow r+ (a,b)$. It should be left to you to show that this really is a surjective homomorphism with the desired kernel.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to define

$$\phi:R/\langle a\rangle\to R/\langle a,b\rangle\;\;,\;\;\phi(r+\langle a\rangle):=r+\langle a,b\rangle$$

It's easy to check the above is well defined , since

$$r+\langle a\rangle =r'+\langle a\rangle\iff r-r'\in\langle a\rangle\le\langle a,b\rangle$$

We also have

$$\ker\phi=\left\{r+\langle a\rangle\in R/\langle a\rangle\;;\;r\in\langle a,b\rangle\right\}\;\ldots$$

I leave the rest for you, just note that a general element of $\;\langle a,b\rangle\;$ is of the form $\;ra+sb\;,\;\;r,s\in R\;$

Comment: Dear DonAntonio I had already built this homomorphism, but I didn't understand why the kernel is $\langle b\rangle$. Thanks

Comment: what is the definition of kernel?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, he wrote "...but I **didn't** understand..." . I think, and hope, he already solved that issue.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik What I didn't understand is why $\left\{r+\langle a\rangle\in R/\langle a\rangle\;;\;r\in\langle a,b\rangle\right\}=\langle b\rangle$

Comment: @user75086: $$r\in\langle a,b\rangle\iff r=xa+yb\;,\;x,y\in R\implies$$$$r+\langle a\rangle =xa+yb+\langle a\rangle=yb+\langle a\rangle\;\;\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: I've already done this, but how a subset of $r+\langle a \rangle$ can be equal to $\langle b \rangle$? I'm trying to prove they are isomorphic without success.

Comment: Who said it has to be equal to $\;\langle b\rangle\;$ , @user75086 ? By the question it should be clear the intention is $\;\langle b\rangle\;$ **inside the quotient** $\;R/\langle a\rangle\;$ !

Comment: I'm sorry, I think my question is wrong. It can't be true that $\left(R/\langle a\rangle\right)/\langle b\rangle\cong R/\langle a,b\rangle$ because $\left(R/\langle a\rangle\right)/\langle b\rangle$ doesn't make sense since $\langle b\rangle$ is not a subset of $R/\langle a\rangle$.

Comment: Oh, I thought all along you *actually* meant the ideal $\;\langle b\rangle +R/\langle a\rangle\;$ ...! If you meant otherwise then certainly the question makes no sense...