# How I prove that $\frac{K[x, y]}{ \langle x^2 - x, y^2 - y\rangle} \cong K \oplus K\oplus K\oplus K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How I prove that $\frac{K[x, y]}{ \langle x^2 - x, y^2 - y\rangle} \cong K \oplus K\oplus K\oplus K$?

Comment: @Noob mathematician Are you sure this made the question more readable?

Comment: it helps me. That is why I edited it.

Comment: I can give you a hint on intuition: By dividing out the ideal $\langle x^2 - x, y^2 - y\rangle$ what you are doing is introducing the condition $x^2 = x$ and $y^2 = y$. Hence you end up with $K[\overline{x}, \overline{y}]$ - note that both adjoint elements are idempotent. Hence what you end up with is all elements of the form $a_1 + a_2 \overline{x} + a_3 \overline{y} + a_4 \overline{x}\overline{y}$. Now you can try to find an explicit isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

We shall be using this [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/593641/779382) .

Observe that 
$$ \frac{\frac{K[x, y]}{\langle x^2 - x\rangle}}{ \langle  {\overline y}^2 - {\overline y}\rangle}\cong \frac{K[x, y]}{ \langle x^2 - x, y^2 - y\rangle} $$

We know that if $I$ is an ideal of a ring $R$ then [$\frac{R[y]}{IR[y]}\cong \frac{R}{I}[y]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1912198/779382). Take $R=K[x]$ and $I=\langle x^2 - x\rangle$  $\implies \frac{K[x, y]}{\langle x^2 - x\rangle}\cong \frac{K[x]}{\langle x^2 - x\rangle}[y].$

So,
$$\frac{\frac{K[x]}{\langle x^2 - x\rangle}[y]}{\langle  {y}^2 - {y}\rangle}\cong\frac{\frac{K[x, y]}{\langle x^2 - x\rangle}}{ \langle  {\overline y}^2 - {\overline y}\rangle}\cong \frac{K[x, y]}{ \langle x^2 - x, y^2 - y\rangle}$$

Now use the fact for any ring (this fact is true by [Chinese Reminder Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1102037/779382)) $$\frac{R[x]}{\langle x^2-x\rangle}\cong R\oplus R$$
**twice**.

Once you take take $R=\frac{K[x]}{\langle x^2 - x\rangle}$ and have
$$ \frac{K[x, y]}{ \langle x^2 - x, y^2 - y\rangle}\cong \frac{\frac{K[x]}{\langle x^2 - x\rangle}[y]}{\langle  {y}^2 - {y}\rangle}\cong \frac{K[x]}{\langle x^2 - x\rangle}\oplus \frac{K[x]}{\langle x^2 - x\rangle}$$
 Then for the second time you take $R=K$ and have
$$\frac{K[x]}{\langle x^2 - x\rangle}\cong K\oplus K$$

Comment: I hope you understand this . If you have problem some where just comment. @GabrielG